# PowerPC and the clrlslwi -or- rlwinm instruction

Tags: assembly, powerpc

I've read the other posts here, but still have a question about PPC and rlwinm.

The example I'm looking at is:

```
li  r0, 0x100
clrlslwi  r9, r0, 27,5 (which afaik is the same as rlwinm r9, r0,5,22,26)
```

First I load r0 = 0x100 
Then Left Shift r0 by 5 so r0 = 0x2000  (No overflow, so no rotate needed)

Make a Mask with bits 22 to 26 set = 0x3e0

AND r0 with the Mask = 0x2000 AND 0x3E0 = 0

I must be doing something wrong...this would always net 0
What am I missing?

Comment: You should format your question (wrap inline code segments in backticks, prefix code blocks with four spaces) and include the actual code you're having trouble with.

Comment: Yah, the value is always 0. So is 2 - 2. What's the problem?

Comment: Is it just me, or are PPC mnemonics *way* harder to decipher than most other architectures?  It was pretty obvious from looking at compiler output what most of the insns do in something like ARM asm, even before I learned much of anything about ARM.  But PPC just looks like gibberish.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Well, ARM used the excess bits in their 32-bit instructions for predicated execution, PPC used them to make instructions do more complex operations. Guess which ISA needed to be completely redone for 64-bit.

Comment: Your analysis looks correct. But what's the question?

Comment: My question is, since this is just going to result in 0, why so many instructions? Like RR said above, why not just li r0,0 ? I guess this just showing how inefficient the compiler used to make this code is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes that's true (Clear left and shift left word immediate)

`clrlslwi rA,rS,b,n (n ≤ b ≤ 31) = rlwinm rA,rS,n,b – n,31 – n`

so 
`clrlslwi  r9, r0, 27,5 = rlwinm r9, r0, 5, 22(27-5), 26(31-5)`